# Create an email forwarder using PHP code and delay the forwarding?

Tags: php, html, cpanel

I managed to find a PHP code to create a PHP forwarder in collaboration with cPanel via this [link](http://forums.glowhost.com/programming-talk/using-cpanel-api-creating-email-account-forwarders-your-own-php-scripts-2798.html).

Using that code... How can I delay the forwarding of such email say by 10 minutes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) , so that you could send mail on particular day/time.

Also see sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097609/how-to-run-php-file-using-cron-jobs)

**EDIT:**
You need to open your linux( I assume) machine and set up a cron.
Open the linux command terminal and type: `crontab -e` to open cron jobs and put across your php file.[How to call a php file from cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs)?

`php /home/USER/public_html/cron.php`

Comment: The code that I found is to create the fowarder on cPanel. Can you provide me with literature to create a php code that checks a particular email and forward it as per you suggestion please? Thanks.

Comment: I checked it. Can you please provide me with the PHP code? I know how to do the cron job.

Comment: There is no code involved in that.
once the cron is setup, thats it.
It(the phpfile) would be called automatically on the day/time you had set it up.

Comment: I know that. what is the code to insert in the phpfile to do that? Thanks

Comment: phpfile should contain code responsible to send emails.
which you have from this link:http://forums.glowhost.com/programming-talk/using-cpanel-api-creating-email-account-forwarders-your-own-php-scripts-2798.html

Comment: Yes but that code is to create email forwarders using cPanel, which I don't want to do. I want PHP code to check my gmail and forward it to a list of recipents.

Comment: Guess that's a different question then!