# How to create a query for cron job schedule

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a script to trigger a message according to the record recorded in the database.
It's like a CRON task.

I have the following record
[image]

I'm going to put a PHP page in the CRON task of Cpanel, but how can I make a query that checks every minute if the record is on the time and day to be fired?

In this image example, you should return the record when:
9 hours 5 minutes Monday, Tuesday or Thursday

See what month and day is with *

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `schedule` 
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
(
dia = DAY( NOW( ) )
)
OR (hora = DAY( NOW( ))    
)
```

How could I check the asterisk and not get into the conditions, I will use OR operator will it work?

Comment: Take a look at [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: Let's say I create an Event Scheduler, how do I call my PHP page to trigger the email I scheduled?

Comment: it was already discussed for many times [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097609/how-to-run-php-file-using-cron-jobs)